in dropdownsearch need a all select option
i  need a dropdownsearch widget in flutter but in that an additional option that is "all select" if i select that option then the all option in the dropdown selected
DropdownSearch<dynamic>.multiSelection(
                                              // items: employeeItems,
                                              dropdownDecoratorProps: const DropDownDecoratorProps(
                                                dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
                                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              onSaved: (d){
                                                print('$d  klklklklklklk');
                                              },
                                              onChanged: (List<dynamic> selectedItems) {
                                                setState(() {
                                                  selectedEmployeeNames.clear();
                                                  selectedEmployeeIds.clear();
                                                  if (selectedItems.contains('Select All')) {
                                                    selectedEmployeeNames = List.from(employeeItems); // Select all items
                                                    selectedEmployeeIds = List.from(employeeItemsId); // Assuming employeeItemsId contains corresponding ids
                                                    selectedEmployeeNames.remove('Select All');
                                                    print(selectedEmployeeNames);
                                                    print(selectedEmployeeIds);
                                                    selectedItems=List.from(employeeItems);
                                                  } else {
                                                    for (var item in selectedItems) {
                                                      selectedEmployeeNames.add(item);
                                                      int index = employeeItems.indexOf(item); // Find index of selected item
                                                      if (index != -1) {
                                                        selectedEmployeeIds.add(employeeItemsId[index]); // Add corresponding id
                                                      }
                                                    }
                                                  }
                                                });
                                              },
                                              
                                              items: employeeItems,

                                              selectedItems:employeeItems,
                                            ),

